# Cannot connect database with php

Tags: php, mysql, database

I can go to database by enter `http://192.168.0.103:37712/phpmyadmin/index.php` on the browser.

But I cannot connect the database by typing this:

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('192.168.0.103:37712', 'root', '');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

IF I change to `$link = mysql_connect('192.168.0.103:3306', 'root', '');`

OR

`$link = mysql_connect('192.168.0.103', 'root', '');`

It shows: Could not connect: Host 'PC' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Comment: 37712 is the HTTP port, not the mysql port. Try 3306 instead (or just leave off the port) or check and see what port mysql is running on.

Answer (score 4):

Remove port `37712` or use `localhost` as you are on local server.

```
mysql_connect('192.168.0.103', 'root', '');
```

**OR**

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
```

**NOTE:** `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. move on `mysqli_*` function asap.